# Can't change the size of a Mailchimp imput field

Tags: css, mailchimp, subscription

I'm having some difficulties with my Mailchimp form that I want to customize a little bit.

Here is the code:

```html
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/horizontal-slim-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
 #mc_embed_signup {
    background: rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.0);
    color: #000000;
    padding: 0px;
        text-align: center;
}

/* Styles the input boxes */
#mc_embed_signup  input {
    width: 200px;
    height:100px
}
  

/* Styles the subscribe button */
#mc_embed_signup .button {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 100 auto;
height: 55px;
}
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//meetwo.us14.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=12989e1d2702ab809b7df0ed4&amp;id=26362168c9" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
 
 <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Your Email" required>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_12989e1d2702ab809b7df0ed4_26362168c9" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="GET BETA INVITE" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

So basically, I have something like this:
[Form screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlZMV.jpg)

As you can see, the email field hasn't the same height of the GET BETA INVITE button and I don't understand when I can change it.

So I'm looking for valuable help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your referenced CSS includes changes to `#mc_embed_signup input.email` which overwrites your `#mc_embed_signup input`.

Try changing this to: `#mc_embed_signup  input.email` and you should be able to change the height of the input aswell.

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/horizontal-slim-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">

#mc_embed_signup {
    background: rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.0);
    color: #000000;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Styles the input boxes */
#mc_embed_signup input.email {
    width: 200px;
    height: 55px
}

/* Styles the subscribe button */
#mc_embed_signup .button {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 100 auto;
    height: 55px;
}

</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//meetwo.us14.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=12989e1d2702ab809b7df0ed4&amp;id=26362168c9" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Your Email" required>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_12989e1d2702ab809b7df0ed4_26362168c9" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="GET BETA INVITE" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Comment: You made my day Robin! Thank you.

One more thing, I would like to make the submit button transparent with a white border. How can I change it?

Comment: You can change the opacity of the input with the CSS property `opacity`. You can also set a border with the `border` property. If you search for these two you'll find the uses for them easily.